# Differences between a pointer and an object while using polymorphism

Tags: c++, pointers, lambda, polymorphism

It seems like I have a confusion about polymorphism and/or pointers. Please see the simple code and the outputs below.

```
class Cell {
    public:
        virtual void call() { std::cout<<"I am a cell"<<std::endl; };
};

class Human: public Cell {
    public:
        void call() override  { std::cout<<"I am a human"<<std::endl; };
};

int main()
{
    Cell *c = new Cell();
    Human h;

    c = &h;

    (*c).call(); // ->>>>>> First call

    auto temp = *c;
    temp.call(); //  ->>>>>> Second call

    auto temp2 = c;
    temp2->call(); //  ->>>>>> Third call

    auto func1 = [&](Cell *x) {
        x = &h;
        return *x;
    };

    func1(c).call(); // ->>>>>> Fourth call

    return 0;
}
```

The outputs are as follows:

```
I am a human
I am a cell
I am a human
I am a cell
```

Could someone please explain me what is going on here?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Which of the four calls confuses you?

Comment: `Cell *c = new Cell(); Human h; c = &h;` -- You've created a memory leak by replacing `c` with another address.

Comment: `*c` is a `Cell&` that references a `Human`; `temp` is a `Cell` (not a `Human` at all); `temp2` is a `Cell*` pointing to a `Human`; `func1(c)` is a `Cell` (also not a `Human`).

Comment: I do not understand why the first call and the second call differs. They are basically the same, right?

Comment: @huckfin `auto` is never a reference. Write `auto& temp` and `[&](Cell *x) -> Cell&` and look at the difference.

Comment: You should replace `Cell *c = new Cell(); Human h; c = &h;` with `Human h; Cell *c = &h;`

Comment: You can use https://godbolt.org/z/ixZ9Kq for such questions. You will find that `(*c).call();` uses the vtable (line 13: `call    qword ptr [rcx]`) and `temp.call();` doesn't use the vtable (line 18 `call    Cell::call()`).

Comment: @ThomasSablik thanks so much for the clarification. I wasn't aware of godbolt, it must help in a lot of situations like this.